# Netbeans C/C++ multiple file compile

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile

I am having problems to compile VERY simple application in netbeans.

So I have created Agent.h, Agent.cpp and I do have a main.cpp, how do I make Netbeans compile my other files, not only main.cpp.

Thanks!

Comment: If your files Agent.h and Agent.cpp are included into netbeans project, will be compiled automatically (no need for you to do anything in order to make them compile). Do you have some error messages during compile?

Comment: Yes I do, it is telling me: undefined reference to `Agent::Agent(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/Simulator/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `Agent::GetName()'

Answer (score 1):

So i had the same issue and my problem was that i tried to include my Agent.h file like this.

```c
#include <Agent.h>
```

this inplies that it is a c++ library and since it's not it cannot be found. Make sure youre file is included using qoutes and not brackets.

```c
#include "Agent.h"
```